Question about Problem $12$ in Chapter $11$ from Kibble & Berkshire's book
I write again the problem for convinience:

A rigid rod of length $2a$ is suspended by two light, inextensible strings of length $l$ joining its ends to supports also a distance $2a$ apart and level with each other. Using the longitudinal displacement $x$, and the tranverse displacements $y_1$, $y_2$ of its ends, as generalized co-ordinates, find the Lagrangian function (for small $x$, $y_1$, $y_2$). Determine the normal modes and frequencies.

I have tried to write the ''rotational part'' of the potential energy of the rod using the angle $\theta=(y_2-y_1)/2a$ through which it rotates about the CM. The correct expression I should find is the following:
$$V=mg\left[l-\sqrt{l^2-\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{2}\right)^2}\right]$$
but I don't understand where the square root comes from.  When I tried to find the potential I said that the vertical position of the CM of the rod is approximately $(y_2-y_1)/2$ so the potential is approximately $V\simeq m\omega_0^2(y_2-y_1)^2/8$ with $\omega_0^2=g/l$, which is the approximate form of the potential above. I know that what I found is correct and this is what I should get, but I want to know where this square root in the potential above came from. I would be grateful if anyone can help.

If the displacement of one end is $y$ you have right-angle triangle of hypotenuse $l$ (the string) and one horizontal side $y$ so Pythagoras says that the vertical side is $\sqrt{l^2- y^2}$. The extra height, $h$,  in $mgh$ is therefore  $l-\sqrt{l^2+ y^2}$.  Now if it is a rotation about the COM, then $y_1=-y_2$ so   $y$ is the same as $(y_1-y_2)/2$.

Shouldn't be $l-\sqrt{l^2-y^2}$? Why is $y$ horizontal side? Shouldn't be vertical or I am missing something? A small figure will help.

The $y$'s are "transverse"  to the originally-vertical strings (but now sloping) , and are therefore horizontal.

I am a little confused with $x$ and $y$ axis placement. $x$ axis points downwards (parallel to gravity) and $y$ axis points to the right, or no?

The question makes it clear that both  the $x$ and $y$ axes are in the horizontal plane:  $x$ is parallel to the rod and the two $y$'s  are perpendicular to the rod, but still horizontal.
